# Split 200 amp service

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

200 amp meter/service at private pole exists.
Underground cable to 200 amp panel in a "shed".
Underground cable between new "house" and existing "shed" exists.
Entire property will run on a 200 amp service by calculations.
"House" has a 200 amp panel.
Canadian electrical code applies.
I want to split the service connection at the "shed" so that both 200 amp service panels are connected to the service main. Neither panel should be a subpanel.
Inspector says it is technically legal because the "shed" doesn't need its own minimum reserved service of 60 amps so we can have one load calculation for the whole setup. What we don't know is what set of panels etc are available (in Canada) to accomplish this kind of feed-thru or split service.

Options:

1. split bus box outside of "shed" that connects both panels somehow.
2. New "shed" panel with feed-thru lugs that connect to "house" panel.
3. Some external box with simple lugs to merge line with 2 loads going to 2 different main breakers. Similar concept to 1 but maybe different implementation?

Anyone aware of how to do this and what equipment is available?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?  There's not much functional difference between a main panel and a subpanel -- the only real difference is that you have to keep neutrals and grounds separate in a subpanel.  And are your existing underground cables 3-wire or 4-wire feeds?

Comment: I agree with Nate in fact the 2020 code we have to have the disconnecting means at a common point in the US, if you don’t have to do that a 3 lug Polaris style connector/ splice for each conductor, may be the least expensive route but both feeders would need to be sized for the service I believe because it won’t be protected until the main panel at each location. Some service panes have double chair lugs that would be the other option.

Comment: How many wires do the existing cables have in them? Is having *both* the shed and house panels set up as subpanels off of a separate main panel an option here?

Comment: Ultimately both panels need to be 200 amp and the feed service is 200 amp. Cable between buildings is AVWU90 (4 cables inside the sleeve -looks like one is ground/bare) and cable from pole to shed is same but what looks like one step smaller. 200amp service is live across the smaller one.

Comment: Maybe it helps to think of it as daisy chaining 200 amp panels on a 200 amp feed. The load calculation for the total draw is ok for 200 amps. If they made marrettes that big, it would be like running two baseboard heaters off one breaker/thermostat. The heaters can handle 15 amps each through them, but they only draw about 5 each usually, and they share a single 15 amp breaker.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel I honestly don't care what kind of hardware it takes. More or different panels etc is fine. The only things I can't change are the cables underground. A special box outside the shed that takes the feed and connects the 2 cables would be perfect. Or a panel that can pass through the full service to the next panel (a pass-thru panel I think it's called)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with oversubscribing panels -- having 2 200A subpanels off a 200A service panel is A-OK, in other words

Comment: @Chris --is the meter at the pole or at the shed?

Comment: Meter is at pole. Underground to shed. Underground from shed to house. I need to figure out what hardware exists (in Canada) that can somehow splice them! We do it all the time inside a junction box with twist connectors. This is the same idea but much bigger!